# Symfony 2 base services configuration

Tags: service, symfony

We are starting to use Symfony 2 in our system, not as a whole but by pulling the components we need and kinda build our framework upon it. We have learned that from these articles

http://fabien.potencier.org/article/50/create-your-own-framework-on-top-of-the-symfony2-components-part-1
And from learning how Silex works as well.

I'm trying to find out how Symfony framework/standard package defines all the kernel.* services but I cannot seem to find that anywhere even after searching all files. Please give me a point if you know.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony2 framework loads bundles from app/AppKernel.php and defines global services in vendor/symfony/src/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/*.xml

Comment: thank you. I do find <service id="kernel" synthetic="true" /> but not sure what "synthetic" means and still not sure where kernel.debug is defined for example.